# optimize this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query but its running soo slow,

```
SELECT 
    wr.wr_re_id as ReID, 
    sum(wr.wr_total) as PRTotal 
FROM 
    Workorder2 w
    INNER JOIN 
    Workorder_Row2 wr ON wr.wr_wo_id = w.wo_id
WHERE 
    (w.wo_type = 1 or w.wo_type = 2)
    AND wr.wr_row_type = 2
    AND w.wo_lo_id like '%'
    AND w.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' 
    AND w.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31'
    AND wr.wr_wo_id IN
        (SELECT 
            wr2.wr_wo_id 
        FROM 
            Workorder_Row2 wr2 
            INNER JOIN Workorder2 w2 ON w2.wo_id = wr2.wr_wo_id 
            AND w2.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' 
            AND w2.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31' 
        WHERE 
            wr2.wr_row_type = 1)
GROUP BY 
    wr.wr_re_id
```

any advice how I can speed it up?  it takes almost 1min to execute.
I think the problem is with the `AND wr.wr_wo_id IN (SELECT ...` but i need this to know if there are product sales on the same workorder that contains a threatment.

Comment: The first step should be to get the query plan from your DB this will show you where long table scans etc are occuring.

Comment: `AND w.wo_lo_id like '%'` looks deadly to me

Comment: @Natrium that statement is basically saying w.wo_lo_id can be anything, even "", but not NULL. I would hope that the query optimizer catches that.

Comment: sorry, I am a bit of a beginner in SQL, where can i find the query plan? /:

Comment: @Alexander, work on your query layout. Code readability is very important in conveying the meaning of the code, that goes for SQL as well.

Comment: the column w.wo_lo_id is of the type integer and does not allow null, so its either 1-999.

but often 1-5 depending on how many different locations there are

Comment: use to_date function when you are comparing dates

Comment: @Alexander - which DB are you using?  For MySQL use the EXPLAIN function, for SQL Server some tips here: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx

Comment: @Niels Boom, thanks for your advice, as previously said i'm quite new to this ):

Comment: @Paolo SQL Server 2005, i will look into that! Thanks!

Comment: @Niels Bom, why not using `and not w.wo_lo_id is null` ?

Comment: @Natrium: I would think that that is faster yes, but I _hope_ the query optimizer would think of that himself. But as you can probably tell I don't _know_ that :)

Comment: @Natrium a silly beginners question, The query optimizer i still cant find. when i query my database i use "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express", i just found out about the Execution Plan, is that the same thing?

Comment: I have no idea where to find. I don't know Sql Server :-) Someone else???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, have a look at your execution plan. It's hard for us to optimize it as we don't know your data.

The thing that jumps out the most is the `wr.wr_wo_id IN (SELECT...)` part. This would be far more efficient as a join, like this:

```
SELECT wr.wr_re_id as ReID, sum(wr.wr_total) as PRTotal 
FROM Workorder2 w
    INNER JOIN Workorder_Row2 wr on wr.wr_wo_id = w.wo_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT wr2.wr_wo_id
        FROM Workorder_Row2 wr2 
            INNER JOIN Workorder2 w2 on w2.wo_id = wr2.wr_wo_id 
        WHERE w2.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' 
            AND w2.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31'
            AND wr2.wr_row_type = 1
    ) T ON T.wr_wo_id = wr.wr_wo_id
WHERE (w.wo_type = 1 or w.wo_type = 2)
    AND wr.wr_row_type = 2
    AND w.wo_lo_id like '%'
    AND w.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' AND w.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31'
GROUP BY wr.wr_re_id
```

It is worth considering whether it would help to add indices. It depends on how often you update/insert into/delete from those tables, and how selective each column is.

ADDITIONAL:

To do the reverse, i.e. to replace `WHERE wr.wr_wo_id NOT IN (SELECT...)`, you would use:

```
SELECT wr.wr_re_id as ReID, sum(wr.wr_total) as PRTotal 
FROM Workorder2 w
    INNER JOIN Workorder_Row2 wr on wr.wr_wo_id = w.wo_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT wr2.wr_wo_id
        FROM Workorder_Row2 wr2 
            INNER JOIN Workorder2 w2 on w2.wo_id = wr2.wr_wo_id 
        WHERE w2.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' 
            AND w2.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31'
            AND wr2.wr_row_type = 1
    ) T ON T.wr_wo_id = wr.wr_wo_id
WHERE T.wr2.wr_wo_id IS NULL
    AND (w.wo_type = 1 or w.wo_type = 2)
    AND wr.wr_row_type = 2
    AND w.wo_lo_id like '%'
    AND w.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' AND w.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31'
GROUP BY wr.wr_re_id
```

However, it is more readable and (I would guess, though try it) more efficient to use:

```
SELECT wr.wr_re_id as ReID, sum(wr.wr_total) as PRTotal 
FROM Workorder2 w
    INNER JOIN Workorder_Row2 wr on wr.wr_wo_id = w.wo_id
WHERE (w.wo_type = 1 or w.wo_type = 2)
    AND wr.wr_row_type = 2
    AND w.wo_lo_id like '%'
    AND w.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' AND w.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM Workorder_Row2 wr2 
            INNER JOIN Workorder2 w2 on w2.wo_id = wr2.wr_wo_id 
        WHERE w2.wo_date_time >= '2010-01-01' 
            AND w2.wo_date_time <= '2010-01-31'
            AND wr2.wr_row_type = 1
            AND wr2.wr_wo_id = wr.wr_wo_id
    )
GROUP BY wr.wr_re_id
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped alot! its down to 0sec (:  
i just found out about the execution plan sorry for not including that.  

i have the same issue with wr.wr_wo_id NOT IN (SELECT..). would this the same as:  

   ) T ON T.wr_wo_id <> wr.wr_wo_id

Comment: sorry for jumping to conclusions! but this was not the correct answer.

the query above does not return the same result as when i use the IN (SELECT...) statement.

Comment: Are you sure? I might be missing something obvious, but they look equivalent to me. In what respect do the results differ?

Comment: the end result i'm looking for is how much Product sales together with a Service are their, grouped by wr_re_id.

Workorder Contains a receipt header, the Workorder_Row table contains the receipt rows.

there are 2 types of rows. (1) Service sales and (2) Product sales.

select * from workorder w 
inner join workorder_row2 wr on wr.wr_wo_id = w.wo_id
WHERE wr.wr_row_type = 2
shows all workorders that has got product sales.

and wr.wr_wo_id IN (SELECT wr2.wr_wo_id FROM Workorder_row wr2 WHERE wr2.wr_row_type = 1).

should give me only the workorders where a Service is sold as well

Comment: its probably me missing something obvious! i bet you are a lot! sharper on SQL then me

Comment: Found a potential flaw...I've added a DISTINCT. When this was missing, then there would be duplicate rows, and the PRTotals would get too large.

Comment: Exactly! this solved it! thank you very much!!

a follow up question  that still remained tho S:

how could i reverse this, if i want to find out product sales without a service in the same receipt. before i used NOT in, 

i tried T ON T.wr_wo_id <> wr.wr_wo_id but that was obviously not right ):

Comment: I'll add it to the answer above.

Comment: sorry for the conclusion jumping again! when i added the DISTINCT to the query its back to 20 seconds! madness... its still faster then IN (SELECT ...) but slow.

anyway i will investigate if i cant run with this and just add a stupid progress-bar to my application :P

Comment: Just for completeness, try that last query, but with `AND NOT EXISTS` changed to `AND EXISTS`. Also, did you look to see whether there are any indices you could try? I assume both tables have a primary key? Beyond that you could try: `CREATE INDEX Workorder2_IX ON Workorder2 (wo_date_time, wr_wo_id)` and `CREATE INDEX Workorder_Row2_IX ON Workorder_Row2 (wr_row_type, wr_wo_id)`  It depends a  lot on your data.

Comment: first query took 15 sec to execute, the 2nd one 14sec (:  

I can say my final result ended up with a database change and program change. I figured out i needed to save a lot more data for my statistics report to be correct. with this i then could rebuild my query and its now running really smooth. i learned alot by this and thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, you can use EXPLAIN to get an idea why your query is slow. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html for more information about EXPLAIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Every SQL datbase engine has a query analyzer that will help you figure out why it's running slow.  But in this case the solution is probably as simple as creating indexes on these columns:

- Workorder2.wo_id
- Workorder_Row2.wr_wo_id

Try adding these indexes as clustered indexes.  If that doesn't work check the query analyzer for further ideas.

- In SQL Server this is found in the Management Studio by entering your query in the query window and clicking on the buttons "Display Estimated Execution Plan" and "Analyze Query in Database Tuning Advisor"
- In MySQL you can use the EXPLAIN command

Note:  Don't worry about your "IN (SELECT ...)" section.  It will be just as efficient as a join on any modern database engine.

Comment: Thanks RobC, i will look into that. this would requirer a database change of some sort i guess?